Bot doesn't respond after send a photo
When I want to send a file from telegram to bot, I don't get any response, additionally in docker I don't have any logs.
from telegram import Update
from telegram.ext import CallbackContext
from . import BaseCommand, command_with_logs, CommandManager

class UploadPhotoCommand(BaseCommand):
    name = "photo"
    description = "send photo"

def __init__(self, manager: CommandManager) -> None:
    self.__manager = manager

@command_with_logs
async def callback(self, update, context):
    try:
        photos = await update.message.photo
        await update.message.reply_text(f'Zdjęcia: {photos}')
    except Exception as e:
        await update.message.reply_text(f'Error: {e}')

Edit:
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from dataclasses import dataclass
from telegram import Update
from telegram.ext import CommandHandler, CallbackContext
from logs import logger

def command_with_logs(func):
    
    async def wrapper(self, update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
        logger.info(f'User {update.message.from_user.id} use command /{self.name}')
        await func(self, update, context)

    return wrapper

class BaseCommand(ABC):
    name: str
    
    description: str = None
    

    def get_handler(self) -> CommandHandler:
        
        return CommandHandler(self.name, self.callback)
    
    @abstractmethod
    async def callback(self, update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
        
        pass

from typing import List, Dict
from telegram.ext import Application, CommandHandler
from . import BaseCommand

class CommandManager:

    def __init__(self, app: Application) -> None:
        self.handlers: Dict[str, CommandHandler] = dict()
        self.descriptions: Dict[str, str] = {}
        self.__app = app

    def setup(self, commands: List[BaseCommand]):
        for command in commands:
            self.handlers[command.name] = command.get_handler()
            self.descriptions[command.name] = command.description
            self.__app.add_handler(self.handlers[command.name])
    
    def add_command(self, command: BaseCommand):
        handler = command.get_handler()
        self.handlers[command.name] = handler
        self.descriptions[command.name] = command.description
        self.__app.add_handler(handler)
            
    def remove_command(self, name: str):
        self.__app.remove_handler(self.handlers[name])
        self.handlers.pop(name)
        self.descriptions.pop(name)

Test case:
/photo - get response 
When use this command without file, bot respond correctly in logs
/photo + photo - don't get response
When use this command with any file, bot doesn't respond anything.
I don't know what is wrong.

Please provide enough code to reproduce the issue. You did not include the definitions of BaseCommand, command_with_logs and CommandMananger. Also please specify what exactly you mean by sending /photo + photo - are you sending a photo with a caption?

Now I added classes and mean of executing command


Also please specify what exactly you mean by sending /photo + photo - are you sending a photo with a caption?


When save a photo in FTP or local server, I want to use a /photo and send photo/file in the same message. Maybe can be a another method, but I don't have any idea, how to get this.


When save a photo in FTP or local server, I want to use a /photo and send photo/file in the same message. Maybe can be a another method, but I don't have any idea, how to get this.

From this description I conclude that the message that you send to your bot looks like this:

This means that the text /photo is in the photos caption, i.e. Message.text is None, while Message.caption contains the text /photo.
CommandHandler does not consider captions, it only considers Message.text. PTB currently does not include any handler or filter that allows to check for commands in the caption. You would have to either

subclass/path CommandHandler to your needs
write a custom implementation of BaseHandler - see also here
or write a custom filter to use in combination with MessageHandler


Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of python-telegram-bot

Write a custom filter does work.
I add too self.handlers[command.name] = command.get_handler_MessageHandler()
